# Calling a signalR hub method from a quartz job with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Quartz job that periodically gets a reading from a temperature sensor and then stores it in the database. I would like to display the new readings on my homepage without reloading so I made a SignalR hub.

```
public class ReadingHub : Hub
{
        public async Task UpdateTempReading(string sensorId, string value, DateTime time)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("TempUpdate", sensorId, value, time);
        }
}
```

And in my `program.cs` I added:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
app.MapHub<ReadingHub>("/readingHub");
```

I also wrote a Javascript client to update the appropriate sensor

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/readingHub").withAutomaticReconnect().build();

connection.on("TempUpdate", function (sensorId, value, time) {
    var valueElement = document.getElementById("temp" + sensorId);
    var dateElement = document.getElementById("date" + sensorId);

    valueElement.textContent = value;
    dateElement.textContent = time;
});
```

When I try to call the ReadingHub from my quartz job, Clients is null so everything gets broken. I am using this to call it.

```
ReadingHub readingHub = new ReadingHub();
await readingHub.UpdateTempReading(tr.TempSensorId, tr.Value, DateTime.Now);
```

I read some other questions and they all seemed to suggest using a hub context, but a Quartz job has to have an empty constructor so I am wondering how can I call my SignalR hub from the quartz job to get the client homepage updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

One of my earlier attempts to resolve this was to open a .net client connection to the signalr hub within the quartz job. I tried to let intelisense help me with this so when I added

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("myurl").Build();
```

The lightbulb went and got a VERY old version of the aspnet.signalR.Client. It was version 2.4.3 or something and should have been 6.0.2 of AspNet**Core**.SignalR.Client. Not having the right version meant there was no .WithUrl in the HubConnectionBuilder, which seemed odd because I was using the Microsoft docs to get this going.

Once I erased the old version and installed the latest one, I was able to open the connection and Invoke the hub method from the quartz job. The code now looks like this, I am starting the connection at the start of the job, and disposing it at the end.

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://hostname:port/myHubUrl").WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();
await connection.StartAsync();
await connection.SendAsync("UpdateTempReading", sensorId, value, DateTime.Now);
```